# Vs code Java runtime can't be located

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I keep having this error I run on window s 10 so any help would be great I have already uninstalled and reinstalled

Comment: It's not a coding problem. Have you look at this : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/112

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As it stands, your question is difficult to answer because of its lack of specifics.  Consider editing your question to include more details about your error, including what command you've entered which produces the error, the exact copy/pasted error response you observe, etc.